# how to get weather icon from weather api in Swift UiKit

Tags: ios, swift, image, api, uikit

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIJfA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWsy4.png)

I am trying to get weather icon from weather api and displaying it on the UI using storyboard and UiKit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qk3C.png)

Am getting these kind of error's while trying

Comment: Copy/paste code rather than only screenshots

Comment: You have a `URL` (or path missing the base URL), not an `UIImage`, you need to download that image. Either use a third party like SDWebImage, Alamofire+Image, KingFisher, etc, or do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I saw in your pictures, you are trying to pass a URL as a param for a swiftui Image() to download it from the web. That is not the way you load images in swiftui. You should use SDWebImage, Alamofire+Image, KingFisher, etc. As an alternative you can use SwiftUI's native AsyncImage to load any image from the web:

`AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://example.com"))`

Comment: Can you provide some explanation how this solves the OP's problem. [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/3124333)

Comment: The OP tagged the question as UIKit, not SwiftUI. And the code is clearly not SwiftIUI.